# Clojure, how to create a vector from elements arriving in a core.async aggregator

Tags: clojure, core.async

I have followed [here](http://elbenshira.com/blog/using-core-async-for-producer-consumer-workflows/) and am getting things called segments arriving at the aggregator. These segments all arrive and I can print them out as they arrive. But what I want to do is make an immutable data structure (a vector) out of them as they arrive. Or even wait for them all to arrive and then make the vector. I'll be able to know when the last one has arrived and sort them. I need to `conj` the arriving segment to the existing so-far-built-up vector. I'm used to creating vectors like this using returns from function calls, but I can't see how this facility is available to me in a thread or go block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumedly, since you are able to receive multiple items, your async code is already in a loop.

In order to build up a vector from the items you get, you should use a loop binding.

```
(def acc-chan
  (>/go-loop [accumulator []]
      (let [item (>/<! source-chan)]
        (if (nil? item)
          accumulator
          (recur (conj accumulator item)))))
```

The `go-loop` call will immediately return a acc-chan, which will receive the loop's return value (the accumulator) when the loop exits. The accumulator is re-bound on each iteration of the loop, adding another item to the end. When source is closed, the accumulator is returned from the loop, and placed onto `acc-chan` where you can read it and use the value.

Comment: So I need to know when and how to explicitly close `source-chan` in order for a nil to come through, and then I'll just be able to retrieve what's there from acc-chan, which will be the vector.

Comment: Yes. You can either use the `.close` method, or just write a `nil` to the channel. Also, I just fixed a typo on the nil check.

Comment: Thanks. I created the aggregator (your acc-chan) with the expected size and returned the last `conj` when that size reached, rather than explicitly closing any channels.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use [`(clojure.core.async/into [] source-chan)`](https://github.com/clojure/core.async/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/async.clj#L939) . Like other "reducer-chans" in the async toolkit, it's also built on the assumption that you will `close!` the source channel when you're ready to receive the result.

Comment: Wouldn't it be the aggregator-chan, so ` (clojure.core.async/into [] aggregator-chan)`. That's where the results end up? If you agree just edit then I'll delete this comment.

Comment: No, `into` (like `reduce`, which it's implemented on top of) takes a source channel to take from as argument and *returns* an aggregator-chan. The aggregator outputs just 1 value, after the source channel is closed. 
(Well, with `reduce` your reducing function can also use `reduced` to short-circuit the reduction before all values have been looked at)